# Reporting options

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

So a few things, when I create a custom report display, by adding additional fields to display. Is there anyway to re-order the fields. so for example if I want lastname, then first name...or other changes?

secondly, is there a way to extend the reporting so i can have reports built? I would like to be able to add an "Action" under the action menu and be able to take the results of the query and send it to a new report?

third, is there a way to bulid a different set of filters for example, what if i want to have the person be able to select a date range or to be able to select a date before, or date after...but the user could decide.

I want to keep everything within Civi framework and not have the user have to go out to a third party app

thanks,
Mark

Comment: I was going to say 'if you are using Drupal then Views may be an easier methodology for doing the above', but your last para put me off saying this (briefly)

Comment: ok, I am using Drupal, how do you use Views to accomplish some of this. I would prefer to say in Civi, but this could be used for now. I am surprised that no one has built a nice extension for reporting withing the framework. The current reporting is so limited.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal Views you can

- build reports with exposed filters, with cols in any order you want, with links to exploded reports and lots more.
- use Contextual Filters or standard filters to ensure the user only sees information pertinent to them
- Civi Relationships (and Views Relationships) to expose to the user other records in civi they should be able to access.

To get started

- if your Drupal db is separate to civi DB then add the prefix required for the civi tables in to your settings.php
- add a view based on CiviCRM Contacts
- add some fields, filters etc and familiarise yourself with Views capabilities

If the above is too hard

- check some of the excellent videos tutorials around on using Views
- reach out to one of the Partners such as Fuzion to at least get you started without too much banging of heads again solid or other types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out some of the extensions that have been built by users and Partners and clients such as the one Fuzion built called [Extended Report](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport)